# Use R connection object from Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, iostream

I am writing some C++ functions for fast reading of binary files. Ideally I would have something like this:

```r
con <- file("path/to/your/file.bin", "rb")
extract1 <- rcpp_process(con)
extract2 <- rcpp_process(con)
# ...
close(con)
```

The Rcpp functions should look something like this:

```c
// [[Rcpp::export]]
RawVector read_bin(SEXP con) {
  
  // cast con to std::ifstream

  // do some magic based on con

  return data;
}
```

What I don't know is what R's `connection` object (`con`) is. I assume just casting it to `std::ifstream` is too easy?

One way is to use the `Rcpp::Function` object and call R's `readBin()`. This is the aproach used in `readr` (cf. [code](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/main/src/connection.cpp)). But I rather do it in plain C to make the processing faster (since `readBin()` will be called millions of times).

Any suggestions? Quick and dirty is also fine as a first step.

Comment: There is a fair amount of prior art in eg my RcppRedis package (taking advantage of my RApiSerialize package wrapping the (otherwise unexported) base R functionality) as well as in the fine packages fst and qs (both of which deal with 'better than rds compression/serialization to and from disk).